# búsqueda con dos campos

Tags: php, mysql

Realizo un modulo de búsqueda de registros, hasta el momento funciona correctamente ya que hace el filtro, funciona buscando con el campo llamado **semana**  de la tabla calculos.

Lo que necesito es si hay alguna forma de ***vincularlo*** con otro campo de la misma tabla campos **id_Control**; *es decir que la búsqueda sea por  la semana y el id_control al mismo tiempo*

Estructura de tabla calculos

```
id_Control     Primaria  Índice   int(10)
idctg_turno    Índice             int(10)
total_horas                       int(10)
horas_normales                    int(10)
horas_extras                      int(10)
Incidencia                        varchar(1000)
semana                            int(10)
```

Codigo donde realiza la búsqueda

```
 <?php
    if($action == 'ajax'){
        // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
         $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
         $aColumns = array('semana');//Columnas de busqueda
         $sTable = "calculos";
         $sWhere = "";
        if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '".$q."' OR ";
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }
        $sWhere.=" order by semana ASC";
        include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
        //pagination variables
        $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
        $per_page = 10; //how much records you want to show
        $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        //Count the total number of row in your table*/
        $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
        $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
        $numrows = $row['numrows'];
        $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
        $reload = './calculos.php';
        //main query to fetch the data
        $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        //loop through fetched data
        if ($numrows>0){

            ?>
```

Comment: Que no solo tendrias que agregar la columna `id_Control` a la variable `$aColumns`?

Comment: @alanfcm Buenas tardes, gracias por responder.  Si asi es, pero mi duda es como lo concateno para que realice esa busqueda ya funciona solo si coloco un campo u otro no los dos como necesito que lo haga

Comment: Intenta asi: `$sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";`